# Bug in R or am I doing the ggplot saving to a list wrong?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to save a set of plots (ggplot) to a list, and it is behaving weird where the last plot overwrites ALL the list indices.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars <- mtcars[, c('cyl', 'am', 'gear', 'mpg')]

plots <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
    plots[[i]] <- ggplot(
      mtcars,
      aes(x = factor(mtcars[, i]), y = mtcars[, 'mpg'])
      ) + geom_point()
}
plots
```

When I try to generally save something to a list, it works fine, as in this example:

```
plots <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
    plots[[i]] <- sample(mtcars$mpg, 1)
}
plots
```

Saving ggplot objects to a list using `lapply` also works just fine, as here:

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars <- mtcars[, c('cyl', 'am', 'gear', 'mpg')]

lapply(
  1:3, function(i)
    ggplot(
      mtcars,
      aes(x = factor(mtcars[, i]), y = mtcars[, 'mpg'])
      ) + geom_point()
  )
```

Any idea what is going on?

BTW - this info might be relevant:

```
> packageVersion('ggplot2')
[1] ‘3.3.3’


> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0     
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin17.0                  
system         x86_64, darwin17.0          
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10                          
day            10                          
svn rev        79318                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out
```

Comment: How do you know the last plot is overwriting all? Remember that the last plot is the one that will be displayed. Have you compared `plots[[1]]` to `plots[[2]]`?

Comment: If you want to store the output in the list, probably, you may initialize `plots <- vector('list', 3)`.  The initialized one is having length 0 `length(list())#
[1] 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the list contains `ggplot` where the x-aesthetics depend on the `i` variable. To be more precise, after you run your code `i` is set to `3`. In particular, the x-aesthetics always shows  `factor(mtcars[, 3])`.

You can verify this by trying the following:

```
print(plots[[1]]) # prints the third plot
i <- 1
print(plots([[1]]) # prints the first plot because now i = 1
```

Here is an alternative workflow you can try:

```
plot_cars <- mtcars %>%
  gather(type, val, -mpg) %>%
  nest(data = c(val, mpg)) %>%
  mutate(plot = map(data, ~ggplot(.x,
    aes(x = val, y = mpg)) + geom_point()))


plot_cars$plot[[1]]
```

Comment: OMG! Had no idea that is how the `aes` behaved. Thank you. Wow!

Comment: @Cett's diagnosis and solution are correct, but it's not `aes` that is the problem.  It's the `for` loop.  `for` loops evaluate lazily.  The `<x>apply` family use forced evaluation.  You can get more information on lazy evaluation [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation).

Comment: Thank you @Limey. I did some experiments and also noticed that my answer was not 100% complete. But I could not pinpoint the main cause of the problem.

Comment: I am still not 100% sure why the behavior of the `for` loop's lazy evaluation is not as described. For example, this piece of code works as "expected": `l <- list(); for (i in 1:10) {l[[i]] <- sample(1:100, i)}; l`